# Time responses (position and speed) of system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-equations, phase-space

This is a basic question regarding state space representation and differential equations.
I want to find the time response of states $x_{1} = x$ and $x_{2} = \dot{x}$ of the following system:

$$
m\ddot{x} + k\dot{x} = 0
$$

The state space is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dot{x_{1}} \\
  \dot{x_{2}} 
 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  -\frac{k}{m} & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x_{1} \\
  x_{2} 
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

What is the fastet and simplest way to calculate the time response of the two states $x_{1}(t)$ and $x_{2}(t)$?

1. Just solve the differential equation for $x$ which equals $x_{1}(t)$ and then get $x_{2}(t)$ using the derivative $\dot{x_{1}}(t) = x_{2}(t)$?
2. Using Laplace, transform the differential equation, solve for $X(s)$ and back transform to the time domain to get $x_{1}(t)$. Then again get $x_{2}(t)$ using the derivative?
3. Or is there another possibility to get the time responses of the states directly from the state space representation?
4. Or is there even another approach?

Comment: In case of this simple linear time invariant system you can use the eigenvalues, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ of the matrix, such that $x_1(t)=C_1e^{\lambda_1t}+C_2e^{\lambda_2t}$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ depend on the initial conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fibonatic above solved your problem by inspection; I'm just  detailing why it was so easy: essentially, diagonalization of the matrix.

For starters, define $k/m\equiv \omega^2$, and you are expected to reflexively recognize the 2x2 matrix involved has paired eigenvalues $\pm i\omega$ with celebrated (un-normalized) eigenvectors $v_1 (1,i\omega)/2$ and $v_2 (1,-i\omega)/2$, respectively; that is,  $x_1=v_1+v_2$ and $x_2=i\omega(v_1-v_2)$. So your system collapses to two decoupled differential equations,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dot{v_{1}} \\
  \dot{v_{2}} 
 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  i\omega & 0 \\
  0 & -i\omega 
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  v_{1} \\
  v_{2} 
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
The solutions are obviously $v_1=C_1 e^{i\omega t}$ and $v_2=C_2 e^{-i\omega t}$, and you *never had to solve a 2nd order differential equation*, options 1 and 2---the central idea behind the exercise. 
This, then, amounts to your option 3:  $x_1=C_1 e^{i\omega t}+ C_2 e^{-i\omega t}$, and the velocity, $x_2=i\omega  (C_1 e^{i\omega t}- C_2 e^{-i\omega t})$.